# WPF .net 4 application does not work properly on Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, visual-studio-2012

I've created a WPF application, C# in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop on Windows 8 with target framework = .Net Framework 4.
When I run the program in Windows 7, it runs but work not correct. For example: When you click on the button click event is not called. On Windows 7 is installed .Net Framework 4. 
Nor any error occurs. Simply does not work any button. If you run into Windows 8, then everything works fine.

Comment: Please provide some problematic code for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With FUSLOGVW.exe spent testing.

```
    The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80131047. No description available.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Release\Myapp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = My-pc\Mypc
LOG: DisplayName = System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes
(Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Release/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = Myapp.exe
Calling assembly : Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Version=1.0.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Release\Myapp.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: PublicKeyToken redirect found in portability config: 7cec85d7bea7798e redirected to b77a5c561934e089.
LOG: Version redirect found in portability config: 2.0.5.0 redirected to 4.0.0.0.
ERR: Failed to apply policy (hr = 0x80131047).
ERR: Unrecoverable error occurred during pre-download check (hr = 0x80131047).
```

Problem solved, after installing the patch 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871